# Wanting to count rows of cells even when the date (which is the criteria) changes in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count rows in another sheet with the date being the common title or criteria between the sheet I am conducting the lookup in and the sheet I am pulling from.
The formula below is what I have:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Headcount Adds'!$C:$C, H$2),COUNTIF('Headcount Adds'!$C:$C,H$2),0)
```

So H$2 is the month of July which returns a 3 which is correct. When I drag the formula over for the month of August, this is the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Headcount Adds'!$C:$C, I$2),COUNTIF('Headcount Adds'!$C:$C,I$2),0)
```

and it gives me a value of 0 which is correct because there is no "August" for it to count in that row but I want it to include the 3 from July. So if it is a 0, I want it to still return the 3 from July.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean `=your_formula+value_of_cell_above`?

Comment: In I$2 couldn't you say what you have + h$2? If so we can generalize that to say + whatever is in the cell one over using offset or just get it right in the second relevant column and drag

Comment: @P.b I think it's +value of cell to the left

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. Thanks for the help!